# What 'Join secondary access path owner' denotes in Join Logical file

Tags: ibm-midrange

I was working with join-logical files and I ran DSPFD command on one of the Join-LF, it shows '*Join secondary access path owne*r' under which it is referring to a join logical file which exist in another library.

Output of EXISTINGLIB/JOINLF:

```
Join secondary access path owner                                       
File  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            ANOTHERLIB/JOINLF
Member  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            JOINLFMBR
```

> Note: Join Physical Files exist in current library(EXISTINGLIB). And JDFTVAL keyword has been used in Join-LF.

Answer (score 3):

The DDS LFs can share access paths...

If you create LF1 with keys, (FLD1, FLD2,FLD3) and LF2 with keys (FLD1, FLD2) the system won't actually create a second acccess path since the access path from LF1 can be used.

This saves disk space and maint overhead.

Comment: Thanks. It means access path is not restricted to a particular library, and system search for the particular set of key fields in all library (disk).

Comment: Consider the access path an internal system object.  The LF/Index object you see in a library is just the surface interface for users.  You can for instance revoke public authority to a LF; yet the system may use the access path in that LF to service a user's query of the physical.